# Excel FIND Error

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the formula to multiply the specific value from cell A2

example: In A2, I want to multiply the value before "." with eleven while at the same time I also want to add value after "."

I came up with

```
=11*LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))
```

It works pretty fine if it does have . in between, but when there is a single value eg, 1-10, etc it throws error `#VALUE!`

All I want if there is a value 2 in cell A2 it should return 22 (2*11=22) instead of error, but if there is 2.5 for instance, it should first multiple `11*2` then adds up remaining 5 (27) in other words it will multiply value before point, then adds up value after point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CORRECTION:** Thanks to @Scott Craner. I missed the point here!

You can try this:

```
=LET(x,A1,decpos,FIND(".",x),before,IFERROR(LEFT(x,decpos-1),x),after,IFERROR(MID(x,decpos+1,LEN(x)),0),11*before+after)
```

More explicitly:

1. Let x be the value in A1
2. Let decpos be the position of the decimal point
3. Let before be the characters to the left of the decimal point, or the entire value if decpos is an error (i.e. there's no decimal point)
4. Let after be the characters after the decimal point, or 0 if decpos is an error
5. Return the calculation `11*before+after`

**Other intepretation where we're adding the decimal as a decimal, not as an integer:**

Assuming the number in A1 is actually a decimal number, then this will work:

```
=11*FLOOR.MATH(A1)+(A1-FLOOR.MATH(A1))
```

Or a little tidier:

```
=LET(x,A1,y,FLOOR.MATH(x),11*y+(x-y))
```

[image]

This will work whether the number in A1 has a decimal point or not.

EDIT:
To handle negative numbers as well as positive numbers, replace `FLOOR.MATH` with `QUOTIENT`:

```
=LET(x,A1,y,QUOTIENT(x,1),11*y+(x-y))
```

Comment: does `floor()` round down for negative values (i.e. does `floor(-5.4)` return -6 or -5)?

Comment: Good point. I've added an edit. Thanks.

Comment: what "x" refers to?

Comment: We just use x as a name for the cell reference A1, so we don't have to have the cell reference in lots of places in the formula and if we want to change the cell reference, we only change it in one place. You can read more about LET here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999

Comment: your formula worked for me thanks a lot.

=LET(x,A1,decpos,FIND(".",x),before,IFERROR(LEFT(x,decpos-1),x),after,IFERROR(MID(x,decpos+1,LEN(x)),0),11*before+after)

Answer (score 0):

your formula assumes that there is a "." and has no facility for the case when there is no "." Look at `iif(expr, truepart, falsepart)`. Use `find()` in the expression to first determine if the field contains a ".", and if it does, use your above formula; otherwise just multiply by 11.

Comment: more details please

Comment: I'd love to have this kind of formula to work but  could not make it myself ;(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following which uses a different method to split the cell value into pieces:

```
=MMULT({11,1},FILTERXML("<group><element>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0.0"),".","</element><element>")&"</element></group>","/*/*"))
```

It first converts the value in A1 to a text representation that always has a decimal followed by some value even if that value is 0. So "10" becomes "10.0" passing into the `FILTERXML()`.

That uses the pretty well-known method of creating an HTML string that the function can parse creating two "real boys"... actual values which then pass into the matrix multiplication.

`MMULT()` then makes it easy to get the sum. One could also use `INDEX()` to get the two (of four in this case) elements needed from a literal (i.e.:  not using `MMULT()`) multiplication by `{11,1}` and `SUM()` to sum them.

Remember that with matrix math, order matters due to how it is done, mechanically, so the array constant (matrix;  `{11,1}` in this case) must precede the array (matrix) produced by `FILTERXML()`. But if desired for some reason, one could transpose its results and put the multiplying array constant after it.

Last thought:  the `TEXT(A1,"0.0")` trick can be used with any other method of breaking down the components, here, or generally with numbers, to make sure there are pieces from before and after the decimal point, regardless of cell formatting.